# Loose steering over anything rough

Tags: ford, suspension, steering, f-150

I have a 2011 Ford F-150, and since we bought a year ago it's always felt somewhat unstable over uneven pavement. The truck tracks straight on the highway, doesn't have any vibration, but anytime I hit a bump on the road I can feel the steering wheel go extremely light. it's to the point where I have to drive with both hands on the wheel almost at all times because if I'm going one handed into a turn the wheel goes so light that my hand drives the steering wheel down unintentionally (not sure if that makes sense?)
It's been to the Ford dealer 3 times, and they always say they can't replicate the problem.
I've asked them to do a front end inspection, and they promised they couldn't see anything.
However, I've driven many things in my life and know that this is not normal...
Could it be a suspension issue? truck currently has almost 70k on stock shocks.
I've tried different air pressures in the tires, and nothing has changed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I'm wondering if the shocks are either weak or bad? Bad shocks can cause an issue like you describe over rough terrain.

Comment: Thanks man! that's what I'm thinking too, it's just hard to actually know and i can't really afford to plug in parts and see if that fixes it.

Comment: I hear yah. I'm not one for remove and replace mechanicing myself.

Comment: LOL. well, I ordered new shocks anyways, so we'll see how that goes